# Как сделать, чтобы открытое миобильное slidemenu можно было скроллить?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Добрый вечер, столкнулся с проблемой. Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы в мобильной версии страницы, при открытом slidemenu скроллилось оно, а не содержимое самой страницы.
Сделал таким образом, содержимое страницы блокируется, а со slidemenu возникли проблемы.

```
$("#main-nav").on("click", toggler, function (e) {
  if ($('.main-index').hasClass('slide-active')) {
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
        $('#slidemenu').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    } else {
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
        $('#slidemenu').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

P.S. делал на bootstrap по этому шаблону http://bootstraptema.ru/stuff/snippets_bootstrap/menu/slidemenu_bootstrap_3/24-1-0-542

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для #slidemenu нужно прописать такие стили:

```
#slidemenu {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```